# what happens to the exisiting users after unpublish of google-chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, installation

I created an extension which was downloaded by few users. Now I want to unpublish the extension, So will it impact the existing users who downloaded and installed the extension. If yes then what will happen?

Answer (score 2):

No. The extension should remain on existing Chrome installs. Google has a remote uninstall feature but has only used it for known malware extensions.

Comment: Any public documentation about this "feature"?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of from the developer side. I've read a couple news articles talking about Google removing malware remotely.

Comment: From [Google Chrome Web Store Terms](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/terms#review): `Google may prevent the Product from being made available in the Web Store, remove the Product from the Web Store, remotely disable or remove the Product from user systems or devices...`