# What happens when I unpublish Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-app

Let's say there are 10,000 installs of my Chrome extension, what happens when I click Unpublish in the https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard? Will it delete this extension from user's browsers automatically or they would have to delete it manually themselves if they want to?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138327/what-happens-to-the-exisiting-users-after-unpublish-of-google-chrome-extension

Comment: common sense would be that your extension does not appear in the store any more, but users who have downloaded it can continue to use it as long as it's compatible with their version of Chrome

Answer (score 7):

No automatic delete will be done. Just no new installs can be done.